# Save string path in a database

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Java  MySQL Database
I'm doing a project on saving a string which is a path name like, "C:\Desktop\" into the database. I had create a entity class to update this path name into database, in java eclipse when i run my program it display the path is store in the database in this format, "C:\Desktop\" but in the database column for this path it only store "C: Desktop", without the '\'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to replace the the `"\"` before you store it in the database. Try:

```
string.replace("\","@");
```

Then your slashes are the `@` symbols. When you read the value again, you can do it the other way.

Comment: So we are both happy this morning. Please vote up if you accept this answer, dude ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `\` with `\\`. Use this to store

```
C:\\Desktop\\
```

instead of

```
C:\Desktop\
```

Learn more about escape sequence in java : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html

Comment: the same problem even i double the \\ it always store them in the database without any \  ...help plz !!

Comment: @achournidhal Can you share the code? Use PreparedStatement instead of Statement if you not.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution is use `/` instead of `\` in path . Or escapes the characters in a String using Java String rules

Answer (score 0):

you may try storing it with forward slash i.e. "C:/Desktop/"